# Aligning output so it's nice and neat in Java

Tags: java

I've got some output that I would like to make look a little better by aligning everything up like a table.

```
Probability: 0.7470986802363135   |    Approximation: 0.7500081297253628   |    Difference: 0.002909449489049254

Probability: 0.71639599474715   |    Approximation: 0.7198106243620636   |    Difference: 0.003414629614913567
```

It's not really necessary but I'm just curious if there is an elegant way to accomplish this? I was thinking I could round the decimals so that each has the same length but I would prefer not to do that if possible.

Here's the code for the output:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++){
    double diff = approxResults[j] - probResults[j];
    System.out.println("Probability: " + probResults[j] + "   |    Approximation: " + approxResults[j] + "   |    Difference: " + diff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define how many decimals you want each of values to have and all of them will be aligned:

```
String.format("%.5f",42.42123456789);
```

will give you formatted value with 5 digits after decimal point 42.42123

In your case you will replace exact number 42.xxx with your variable 'diff'

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
System.out.println("Probability: %9.6f | Approximation: %9.6f | Difference: %8.5f%n, 
                   probResults[j], approxResults[j] , diff);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double r = Math.round(a * 1000) / 1000.0;
```

If you want to use the values afterwards in your program also, you can use the Math.round function which would give you the value rounded upto specific decimals (Here it would go upto 3 digits because I used 1000).

Comment: You can also write it as `Math.round(a * 1e3) / 1e3;` to highlight the number of digits used in the rounding.